# Word for when you ignore someone's wisdom because you don't think they really understand?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

The best example is when teenagers and young adults say "yeah right" to their parents and elders who provide sound advice because they are convinced that their situation is new or different.  It's sort of patronizing but maybe something else.  When you just go along with whatever they say, but inwardly you seriously doubt that they know what they are talking about.  Is there a word for this?

Update:  Perhaps "incredulity"?

Comment: Hello, Iwantmyphd. Although not tagged as such [single-word-request], your question would probably fall into that category. These kinds of questions generally require a sample sentence to display how the target word might be employed. IMHO, "patronize" works.

Comment: I might add the retort "Whatever..." to this complaint.

Comment: Skepticism?....

Comment: It could be ironically. If you say something "ironically", you do not mean it and are saying it as a joke.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure why this is considered opinion-based, and I'm not sure how I would edit it so that it doesn't sound opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

When you agree (or pretend to) in order to 'shut someone up' (or, 'down') it's called: ***'yessing' them to death***.

*"You be home by midnight!"*

"Yeah, sure, whatever..."

*"I mean it! Don't just* ***'yes' me to death***!"